# Динамическая runtime установка значений для Select2 контрола с свойством multiple (множественного выбора)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select2

Есть обычный SELECT он преобразован в SELECT2 контрол с свойством multiple (множественного выбора). Есть массив с некоторыми опциями из SELECTа и нужно перебирая этот массив установить нужные значения в SELECT2.

Пока получается установить только последний из них вот так:

```
$("#select").select2('val', [2,4,5]);
```

Как можно установить несколько значений сразу, что бы они все попали в поле с метками выбора?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так :

```js
$("#select").select2({
  data: [
    {
      id: 'value',
      text: '1 Text to display'
    },
    {
      id: 'value',
      text: '2 Text to display'
    },
    {
      id: 'value',
      text: '3 Text to display'
    },
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  
  <select id="select">
  </select>
```

Comment: спасибо елена за ответ проверять не стану тороплюсь, нашел другое решение. смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так решилось:

```
$("#select").val([2, 4, 5]).trigger("change");
```

Через триггер заработало.